# Hyphen and &nbsp; differences between Firefox and other browsers

Tags: html

Firefox and seems to render a hyphen followed by `&nbsp;` differently to other browsers. Here is some test code that demonstrates the problem:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue;width: 50px">
        This text can break. Do&nbsp;not&nbsp;-&nbsp;break&nbsp;this&nbsp;text.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how in Firefox the second sentence does not break, but in Chrome and IE it breaks at the hyphen.

Does anyone know a good workaround so that the break does not occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the "minus" sign in your code allows breaking.
There are lots of ways how you can write a "horizontal line" in HTML. `&ndash;`, `&mdash;`, `-`. There is ["A list apart" article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/emen/) describing all the possible ways.

But also several specific Unicode characters exist which can be used by their code point numbers. One of them is a "non-breaking hyphen", which can be written like this: `&#8209;`.

I tried using it in your example and now the text does not break.

Answer (score 0):

Naivist has the answer, but, for the record, I ended up using CSS's *white-space: nowrap;*